# Ajax BeginForm doesn't work after Dynamically created

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating a form that gets inserted dynamically after a user clicks a button.

The way it works is. Click a Button --> Return Partial View --> Insert it in the View. The partial View has a Ajax.BeginForm and I wanted it to be submitted synchronously. However what I get is a Full postback. I do have the files and I have tested it without getting the form from ajax and it works. I am guessing it has to do with the binding.

Comment: please share your View, partial, and Controller

Comment: Are you sure your AjaxOptions are set correctly?